# Structure of 802.11 data field

Tags: ieee-802.11, data

I can't find a good diagram or anything else, that shows the structure of the data/payload/frame body of a 802.11 paket. Is there also any difference between the protocol version, or do all of them use the same 'layout' for the data field? Also, a lot of books write 'data', some 'payload' and other 'frame body'. I think everything means the same, but just in case: Is this right?

I'm just learning more about the 802.11 standard.

Comment: Google is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IEEE 802.11 is a series of layer-1/2 protocols. The payload of 802.11 frames is a layer-3 protocol (IPv4, IPX, IPv6, AppleTalk, etc.). The payload of a frame has nothing to do with 802.11 because the frame could be carrying any of a  number of layer-3 protocols, hence you will not find any definitive description of what the frame payload looks like (it can be anything).

Layer-2 protocols don't know or care what is in their payloads, not do layer-3 protocols care what is in their payloads, etc. This is the abstraction of the network stack. Each layer of the network stack is independent of the other layers.